# mass effect 3 save editor conrad verner

Tags: mass-effect-3, mods

Does anyone know PlotIDs for Gibbed Save Editor to add Conrad to ME3? I flagged Charm him in ME1 and I unflagged Shot him in foot in ME2 - still don't see him.

Answer (score 1):

For ME1, everything in [Citadel: The Fan] should be checked (I think if you leave "Got him killed" unchecked though, it should be okay).  Make sure [Citadel: Rita's Sister] is also checked.

For ME2, uncheck [Illium: Conrad Verner], which you already have.

Comment: Nope, just tried it and still don't see him. Besides, on many forums it said to leave "intimidated him" unchecked, so I'm flagging "Charm him" and "Met him" plus "Rita's sister" of course. In ME2 I leave uncheck. Does he must appear near memorial in docks, right? Or after I get task to repair medi-gel stations?

Comment: Yes, Conrad doesn't show up until you get the medi-gel quest.  He should be around #2 here, where I am: http://i.imgur.com/EUnliqu.jpg (If "Intimidate" isn't working, I'm not sure what the problem might be, all my saves have that checked for some reason, even if I _didn't_ intimidate him so I thought it might have something to do with that.)

Comment: Nope, still don't see him ;( I've tried all combinations... Maybe is there some Plot IDs those I should to check or the other boolean parameters.. And what version of Gibbed Save Editor do you use? I've got 89.

Comment: I'm using build 90.

Comment: Where did you get it??? I can't find it in google. Can you share the link pls?

Comment: Here's a direct link: http://svn.gib.me/builds/masseffect3/saveedit-r90_b115.zip  I've been using the builds here: http://svn.gib.me/builds/masseffect3/

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it next time. Couldn't to wait - so I'm going to next missions without Conrad now. I'll inform you the results next try.

Comment: Nope. Still don't see him even with save editor build 90. Maybe there is a special order of mission completing in docks, right after Cerberus assaulth? I don't know... I can even send you my profile with save game file before start mission repearing medi-gel stations... to take a look what is wrong....

Comment: still if anyone has a boolean paramets about Verner then I can check it in editor... I've got feeling that check box dont work well...

Comment: You're welcome to upload it somewhere.  I'll take a look at it and see what turns up on my save editor.